# Video editor that can auto-remove still frames

Tags: video-editing

I am looking for a video software that can remove still frames from a video.

The use case is for screen recordings of computer games, where you might imagine a chess game that we want a quick recap of, so if a live recording of the board is 30 minutes, most of that time is spent thinking, and to get a quick recap of the game we remove all those periods of thinking and only show the actual moves, reducing the video from 30 minutes down to a few seconds, which will reduce the file size by something like 99%. The video can then be watched frame by frame.